# ERROR in jQuery for some reason and I can't figure out why

Tags: javascript, jquery

### Could someone take a look? I believe there is something wrong with the jquery source code but I can't come to a more specific explanation than that.

### https://codepen.io/SebastianSapien/pen/wWJXMB

**app.js:**

```
//Hide hints
$("form span").css("display", "none");

//create som variables to make the code easier to follow
var $password = $("#password");
var $confirmPassword = $("#confirmPassword");

//when focusing (clicking) on the password text input, show the
//hints until the length of the input reaches 8.

//specifies whether the password specified is long enough
function passwordIEnough() {
    return $(this).val().length > 8;
}

//specifies if the password and confirm password boxes are equal
function passwordsAreEqual() {
    return $password.val() === $confirmPassword.val();
}


function passwordEvent() {
        if ( passwordIsEnough() ) {
            $(this).next().css("display", "none");
        } else {
            $(this).next().css("display", "inline-block");
        }
}

function confirmPasswordEvent() {
    if ( passwordsAreEqual() ) {
        $(this).next().css("display", "none");
    } else {
        $(this).next().css("display", "inline-block");
    }
}
```

**html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Dropdown</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>

    <form action="#" method="post">
    <h2>Professional Form</h2>
        <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" id="uname" name="username">

        <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
            <!-- <div class="arrow-left"></div> -->
            <span>Atleast 8 characters</span>

        <label for="confirmPassword">Confirm Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="confirmPassword" name="confirmPassword">
            <!-- <div class="arrow-left"></div> -->
            <span>Please confirm your password</span>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
    </form>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </body>
</html>



$password.focus(passwordEvent).keyup(passwordEvent).focus(confirmPasswordEvent).keyup(confirmPasswordEvent);

$confirmPassword.focus(confirmPasswordEvent).keyup(confirmPasswordEvent);
```

**What the console says:**

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
>   jquery-1.12.4.min.js:4

Comment: What is purpose of two each `.keyup()` and `.focus()` event handlers attached to same element?

Comment: You misspelled the name of the `passwordIsEnough()` function, and it won't work anyway - it tries to use `$(this)` but when it's called `this` won't be anything useful.

Comment: Don't use the minified version of libraries during development. That's meant for deployment.

Comment: @squint what should I use?

Comment: The unminified version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that "this" in your case is a reference to the window, not to the textbox as you are expecting. $(this) will only work inside of a bound event handler. Try using a different method of gaining access to your textbox like `$("#password").val()`, or use `$("#password").focus(function(){})` for your logic.

Comment: Thanks alot! Greatly helped

Answer (score 0):

within passwordEvent and confirmPasswordEvent "this" is the HtmlInputElement that caused the event, passed in through the jQuery event handler.

I don't believe this scope is passed to "passwordIsEnough" and the "this" scope may be windows.  hit it with a debug point with your browser debug tools.

You can also call it with "passwordIsEnough.call(this)" to invoke the method where "this" will be the same scope from the calling method.